# How to add a players name to an array if they touch a part. - Roblox - Lua Coding

Tags: arrays, lua, touch, roblox

I've been have trouble recently when i try to add a player to an array if a part is touched, but i cant seem to get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
                playerWin = {}

        game.Workspace.SharkSurvival.givewin.Touched:Connect(function(TouchedPart)
            if TouchedPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                local Character = TouchedPart.Parent
                local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Character)
                local AlreadyInTable = false
                -- Now make sure the player isn't already in the array
                for _,OtherPlayer in next,playerWin do
                    if OtherPlayer == Player then
                        AlreadyInTable = true
                    end
                end
                if not AlreadyInTable then
                    -- Add them to the array!
                    table.insert(playerWin,Player.Name)
                end
            end
        end)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

I wanted the first object of my array to be the player who touched the part.